# sqlite ODBC driver and "attach" statement

Tags: sqlite, odbc

I want to use the sqlite ODBC driver from http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/ and start with an `ATTACH` statement, as I need joint data from two databases. However the driver returns no dataw when provided the following SQL:

```
attach 'my.db' as mydb; select 1
```

It however correctly complains with `only one SQL statement allowed` when the first statement is indeed a `SELECT`:

```
select 2;attach 'my.db' as mydb; select 1
```

Checking at the source, a `checkddl()` function analyzes if the provided requests contains DDL (Data Definition Language) statement. Before digging in the complete code, question is:

- did someone manage to issue a `select` after an `attach` with this driver ?

Comment: Hm... And why is it a problem to execute one statement at a time?

Comment: @PChemGuy The use case is an Excel report where you can not execute a sequence of statement. You can only put some SQL in one textbox that will be provided to the ODBC driver for execution.

Comment: Then make an ADODB based macro instead of putting SQL in a text box.

Comment: If you have substantial amount of data, it is going to be very slow, unless you use Excel 2002/2003.

Comment: I have no performance problem with the current amount of data. Currently it works when data is in one database. Splitting the content for logical reasons is why is want to use ATTACH. I favor any non-VBA solution above all.

Comment: Yeah, that is problematic